# How to add an onClick listener in typescript react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

Trying to attach an `onClick`-Listener to a `div`-Element like this

```js
      useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current === null) {
          return;
        }
        const handleClick = (el: HTMLDivElement, e: MouseEvent) => console.log("clicked");
    
        const el = ref.current;
    
        el.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
        return () => el.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
      }, [ref]);
```

but IDE complains:

[image]

Any advice on how to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: The first argument of the click handler would be the `MouseEvent`. The `this` parameter isn't a real parameter, it's a TypeScript-ism only used to indicate the value of this when the callback is called (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)). But to use that it would have to be defined as a regular function, not an arrow function, and in that case, you would specify the first parameter as `this: HTMLDivElement` (it has to be called "this").

Comment: @M. Desjardins Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of the click handler would be the `MouseEvent`. The `this` parameter isn't a real parameter, it's a TypeScript-ism only used to indicate the value of this when the callback is called (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)).

To use it, you would have to use a regular function, not an arrow function:

```js
const handleClick = function (this: HTMLElement, e: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(this, "clicked")
};

const el = document.createElement("div");
el.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

Otherwise, if you don't need to use `this`, you would just leave it off and use the event as the first parameter:

```js
const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log("clicked")
};

const el = document.createElement("div");
el.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```